# Is there a way to use SVM to build a model that contains a pre-defined percentage of the training data?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm

Say, I wish to use LIBSVM to build a model that contains 70% of the training data. Is that possible?

Comment: Do you mean to force use 70% of the data as support vectors? yeah.. it is possible, May I ask.. why do you want to do that?

Comment: The question is vague. Do you want 70% of the training data to be support vectors like @Pedrom says, or you want to just use 70% of the training data to actually train your model (in which case, the other 30% of data is not "training data" anymore)

Comment: If an answer was useful you may consider accepting it, or upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

There are no techniques that allow you to specify exactly how many support vectors the model will contain in advance. A possible exception are fixed-size formulations of least-squares SVM which allow you to specify the size of the kernel in advance (and for LS-SVM every training instance is a SV).

Note that a fraction of 70% support vectors is very high for typical SVM in most cases, so I can't see an immediate reason why you would want this.

You can, however, specify a minimum fraction of support vectors using formulations like the nu-SVM by Schölkopf et al:

B. Schölkopf, A. Smola, R. C. Williamson, and P. L. Bartlett. New support vector
algorithms. Neural Computation, 12:1207-1245, 2000.

In this formulation you will have at least the fraction nu support vectors (with 0 < nu <= 1). nu-SVMs are implemented in LIBSVM, for example (use `-s 1` for nu-SVC or `-s 4` for nu-SVR). For more information, you may refer to [this pdf (page 4)](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf) or google nu-SVM to find various papers about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the tools folder of libsvm you will find a python script called subset.py. You can use it to randomly select a subset of your data for training.